# In Eclipse plugins, is there a programmatic equivalence to the markerAnnotationSpecification extension point?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

The extension point `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` is used to change how certain user-defined text annotations appear in the editor.

Is there a way to create or modify or override these programatically from a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-dynext/

It talks about adding extensions programmatically using addContribution().